# Errors when building game to any platform

Tags: unity, build-process

As a newer Unity user, I've never had this problem before. I looked around on the internet and didn't find any help except to reimported all my assets which did not help.

I get these errors when building to any Platform:

> Assets/Scripts/MainMenuManager.cs(41,21): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `EditorApplication' does not exist in the namespace`
>   UnityEditor'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
>
> Build completed with a result of 'Failed' UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors   at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187
>   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.GetAnimationModeDriver ()
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:474)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_previewing () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:340)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_recording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:390)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopRecording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:421)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopPreview () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:361)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:105)
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.GetAnimationModeDriver ()
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:474)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_previewing () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:340)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_recording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:390)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopRecording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:421)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopPreview () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:361)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:105)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowState.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowState.cs:315)
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.GetAnimationModeDriver ()
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:474)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_previewing () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:340)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_recording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:390)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopRecording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:421)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopPreview () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:361)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:105)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowState.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowState.cs:315)
>   UnityEditor.AnimEditor.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimEditor.cs:363)
>   UnityEditor.AnimationWindow.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindow.cs:72)
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.GetAnimationModeDriver ()
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:474)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_previewing () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:340)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.get_recording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:390)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopRecording () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:421)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.StopPreview () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:361)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowControl.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowControl.cs:105)
>   UnityEditorInternal.AnimationWindowState.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimationWindowState.cs:315)
>   UnityEditor.AnimEditor.OnDisable () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Animation/AnimationWindow/AnimEditor.cs:363)

I don't know what any of this means and I can't find any other information on it. I haven't upgraded Unity or anything like that.

Comment: Looks like you may have some files using UnityEditor that aren't under a folder called "editor". Can you search your codebase for "UnityEditor" and report back on what you find?

Comment: @DMGregory I don't get anything in my project assets directory

Comment: What about Assets/Scripts/MainMenuManager.cs, line 41?

Comment: @DMGregory That's one of my scripts, line 41 is a simple 
"UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;" which acts as a quit button the editor.

Comment: @DMGregory This is going to sound very dumb, but commenting out that one line of code fixed it... Do you have any theories on why that line caused a problem in Unity but the game played in the editor and VS though it was fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main blocker here looks like:

> Assets/Scripts/MainMenuManager.cs(41,21): error CS0234: The type or namespace name EditorApplication' does not exist in the namespace
>     UnityEditor'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

It states that you have a script (MainMenuManager.cs) attempting to call code (`EditorApplication`) from the namespace `UnityEditor`, which does not exist.

It does not exist for your *built game* because the UnityEditor library, which contains that namespace, is not included in built games.

A workaround is using preprocessor define checks if you must have edit-time and runtime code in the same script, e.g.:

For editor-only code:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
#endif
```

For using different code in the editor to any other platform (build target):

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;
#else
Application.Quit();
#endif
```

*(note that in the above examples, the syntax highlighter colours lines beginning with `#` as comments. They are in fact the pertinent parts of the examples)*

[Unity has documentation on the support and use of these preprocessor defines for platform-dependant compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). The preprocessor modifies the code sent to the compiler. When you build, `#if UNITY_EDITOR` is false and the compiler will never even see the code inside that block.

---

To explain why all may seem okay, Unity will share project files with Visual Studio  which allow it to use the Visual Studio C# compiler for it's own functionality, e.g. error checking. To enable this functionality in VS for editor scripts, Unity includes a reference to the UnityEditor library for an 'editor' project to VS - making VS report that there are no errors because it's tools have a reference to the UnityEditor library whereas the Unity compiler that builds your game does not.

Comment: Ok, but I have both "UnityEditor.EditorApplication.isPlaying = false;" and "Application.Quit();" in the same script already.

Comment: Did you notice the lines `#if UNITY_EDITOR` and similar? They are the ones which say which bits of code will get used. It may have been unclear as they are coloured the same as comments here.

Comment: Ok, I see, thank you